# Sencha Touch - RESTful load() specific instance URL problem (Store/model)

Tags: sencha-touch

It seems there is a problem with loading a specific instance (load() function) using the rest proxy in a model/store object. example:

Code:

```
Ext.regModel('User', {
    fields: ['id', 'name', 'email'],

    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url : '/users'
    }
});

//get a reference to the User model class
var User = Ext.ModelMgr.getModel('User');

//Uses the configured RestProxy to make a GET request to /users/123
User.load(123, {
    success: function(user) {
        console.log(user.getId()); //logs 123
    }
});
```

This code is copied from Sencha touch's API. the generated URL is http://localhost/users?_dc=... instead of the desired (and documented) url http://localhost/users/123.

it also happens when using the store.load with a parameter.

Am I doing something wrong here?
 Thanks
 T

Answer (score 1):

It seams the id parameter has been documented but not implemented. This has been discussed in the sencha forum [[link](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?122595-Model.load-not-sending-id-loading-all-models)]. A few non complete fixes are written in post #8 and post #13.